# How to implement for loop on below json body in postman

Tags: javascript

```
 "status": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "VehicleId": 7,
            "VehicleName": "9960612893",
            "Make": null,
            "Model": null,
            "VIN": null,
            "RegistrationNumber": null,
            "DeviceSerialNumber": "9960612893",
            "DriverName": null,
            "DriverUserId": 0,
            "FleetId": 0,
            "FleetUnitId": 0,
            "ParametersData": "{\"altitude\":510.45196533203125,\"gps_speed\":4.3,\"gps_time\":\"2019-09-10 12:44:06\",\"latitude\":18.5566919,\"longitude\":73.7934332,\"mobile_id\":\"9960612893\",\"record_time\":\"2019-09-10 12:44:06\",\"serial\":\"9960612893\",\"vin\":\"\"}",
            "LastConnectedTimeEpoch": 1568119446,
            "LastConnectedLocalDateTime": "10/09/2019 12:44:06",
            "ModelYear": null,
            "ManufacturedIn": null,
            "Odometer": 0.0,
            "FleetName": null
        }
    ],
    "total": 0,
    "message": null
}
```

Comment: You can't implement for loop in postman .Please elaborate your question more.Thanks

Comment: i m trying to access keys element using for loop using                                   
      for(i=0; i<jsonData.data[0].length; i++)

Comment: and why you need to do this in postman? You can use a shell script for example